# How to change default color theme for ansi-term?

Tags: colors, ansi-term

I have the package `color-theme-buffer-local`, which allows you to change the default color theme on a per-buffer basis.

I added this to my config:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode 
          (lambda nil (color-theme-buffer-local 'color-theme-black-on-gray (current-buffer))))
```

And it doesn't have the intended effect of forcing all `ansi-term` buffers to have the `color-theme-black-on-gray` value.  How do I get `ansi-term` to respect the colors I am trying to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you want is `term-mode-hook`, not `term-mode`.  Rewrite it as:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook #'my-awesome-hook)
```